# What is the speed limit with only one sign?

Tags: speeding, virginia

[image]
Ignore the side road I added (opps!) Basically if I am driving down the screen what is the speed limit? It is a workzone but the sign is only posed going up. The road goes back to 55 after the work zone.

Comment: I think the work zone itself requires the decrease in speed. In other words, when entering a work zone, regardless of the existence of a sign giving you a speed limit, drivers are required to slow down.

Comment: @A.fm. Don't think you are right. Being in a work zone doesn't automatically tell you the speed limit because speed limits in work zones vary. I would think that you have to follow the posted limit. My strong suspicion is that there should have been a sign posted in your direction which you missed, or was obstructed by something, or accidentally wasn't put up yet, or was removed improperly or due to misadventure. It is possible, however, to have a work zone that only covers one side of the road and this is common in median divided highways. The safe bet would be to slow to 25 mph if you knew.

Comment: @ohwilleke I know I didn't miss it since I drive through it daily

Comment: It is simply not there

Comment: @ohwilleke I agree about speeds varying and I was more stating that if one sees a work zone, one should simply assume one must slow down. Not an exact answer nor a legal one, by any means. I know in Michigan, due to a spate of collisions involving cars and workers, penalties for any sort of speeding in any work zone were drastically increased some years ago. Just an intuitive thing for me at this point.

Comment: @A.fm. well they just installed a second sign fixing the problem

Answer (score 2):

The speed limit is the last legally posted limit on the stretch of road, as I understand it. If 55 were the last speed posted, that would be the limit.

However, many (most? all?) states don't require that you be driving faster than the posted limit to be guilty of speeding or a similar violation. As I understand it, typically laws require that drivers drive at safe and prudent speeds given the road and conditions. In these cases, posted limits may be identified in the law as prima facie evidence of unsafe or imprudent driving. However, if the posted limit is 55 in a busy construction zone, you very well still might be violating the law - and be ticketed, and lose if you challenged that ticket - if 55 is too fast.

So - the speed limit can be 55 and you can be ticketed for doing 55. The absence of a correct posted limit does not absolve you of your legal responsibility to meet the "reasonable person" standard.