# What actual speed limit applies if a temporary low speed sign is placed on only a high speed express lane?

Tags: speeding

Suppose the express lane on a freeway has a 30 miles per hour work zone sign. After this sign, the entire freeway's speed limit is 85 miles per hour.

What is the exact speed limit for the road if the low speed limit is only on the express lane?

Comment: Hi, please improve your question quickly. If not, I will improve it quickly with just a single edit.

Comment: Ok now. Nij has edited this.

Comment: **Please stop editing posts with minor and insignificant changes.** All changes should be made at the same time. If you cannot find all appropriate edits in one attempt, save them up for later. Gaming the system to obtain rep for multiple minor edits on a single post is not appropriate behaviour, and has been flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: Ok. 5a52 is not me. 5a52 are gaming the editing system. So I learned it. I will never game it again.

Comment: Which jurisdiction is this question referring to?

Comment: No. Please see my question entirely.

Comment: @user298438 you do not need any reputation to edit your own posts. You also do not earn any reputation by editing your own posts. Please contribute meaningfully to the site by asking good questions or providing good answers, or by making meaningful edits to posts that actually need them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the speed limit is *only* on a express lane in a freeway, it means the cars in the express lane on the freeway *must* be slowed down to 30 miles per hour or slower, but the cars in the *other* lane (the collector lane) in the freeway must be 85 miles per hour or slower.

If *after* the speed limit on the express lane there is a 85 miles per hour speed limit on the express lane, the cars in the express lane *must* be 85 miles per hour or slower *after* the work zone speed limit. If not, then *all* cars in the express lane *only* can be 30 miles per hour or slower than 30 miles per hour.

Comment: Is work zone down on only express routes?

Comment: Yeah!!!! and the speed limit for the other lane are 85.

Comment: What if the westbound/southbound lane's speed limit is 30 miles per hour?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22722/what-is-the-speed-limit-with-only-one-sign

Comment: Yes! [What is the speed limit with only one sign?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22722/what-is-the-speed-limit-with-only-one-sign)

Comment: The answer doesn't explain that.

Comment: No. See their question and some of the comments.

Comment: The comments would help you to understand that.

Comment: Just see their comments.

Comment: Hey, could you stop editing this post? I tried to compromise on the edit. You don't like my sentences?

Comment: Yeah, but I now edit others.

Comment: Now edit others? You are still editing my post!

Comment: I tried to compromise on the edit again.

Comment: Compromise on the edit???

Comment: Yeah. But I don't have enough reputation to compromise edits. It is unlocked at 7k reputation.

Comment: I'am trying to earn reputation by editing posts!

Comment: Now, I could be lost, so I could make many edits to the 75 reputation, and I will set a bounty for you.

Comment: **Please stop editing posts with minor and insignificant changes.** All changes should be made at the same time. If you cannot find all appropriate edits in one attempt, save them up for later. Gaming the system to obtain rep for multiple minor edits on a single post is not appropriate behaviour, and has been flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: Ok. 5a52 is not me. 5a52 are gaming the editing system. So I learned it. I will never game it again.

Comment: @5a52 you do not need any reputation to edit your own posts. You also do not earn any reputation by editing your own posts. Please contribute meaningfully to the site by asking good questions or providing good answers, or by making meaningful edits to posts that actually need them.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that driving at 85 miles an hour just besides cars going at 30 miles an hour (a 55 miles per hour speed difference) is extremely dangerous and could cost your life. This is a situation where it absolutely doesn't matter what is legal, what matters is that you behave in a way that keeps you and others alive.

In most places there is a law that you must not drive at an unsafe speed. If you drive 85 mph besides a 30 mph express lane, and some accident happens, you can bet that any judge will tell you that you were driving at an unsafe speed, and the accident was your fault.